# How to implement input textbox as mandatory field in IOS

Tags: ios

I am new to Iphone development. This will be the so simplest one to the experts. But I searched in google, I cannot find anything.

I want to implement Input textbox as mandatory field by manually and programmatically. In android, it's easy to implement. But I don't know how to implement in IOS.

Would you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: What kind of mandatory effect would you like to create?

Comment: On button click, user should not leave textbox as empty.

Comment: If i were to do this in xcode natively I would be looking at the areas where I handle dismissing the keyboard, but only dismiss it if `[textFieldName.text length] > 0`.

Comment: Make a label having `*` previous to it and validate that field in the button action.

Comment: Yes we can validate field in button action. But how to show in the for the user .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell me if i'm wrong, but i think, basically, that you want to give feedback to your user, is that right ? In that case, you may have a few options that can apply :

1- Like LML said, you can add an alert view this way :

```
UIAlertView *yourAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Explain more" delegate:yourDelegate cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Note that you have to set a delegate only if you want to do action **after** the user has clicked a button in your alert, if not, you can set it to nil. See [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) for more information.

2- The other way is based on [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods. When your user is editing the field, you can show a feedback icon in it, or close to it. You can display a red cross in the field by default and disable your validation button. When the value turns right, display a green check icon and enable your validation button.

Basically, you can do it like this :

In the **viewDidLoad** of your viewController, add the following :

```
[yourField addTarget:self action:@selector(giveFeedback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This way, anytime the field's value is modified, your **giveFeedback** method will be executed. That is the UIControlEventEditingChanged.

Then, your **giveFeedback** could be like this :

```
- (void) giveFeedback:(id)sender {

    // Here, field is valid when it's 7 characters long
    if (self.yourField.text.length == 7) {
        self.checkmark_img.hidden = false; // Pops out the green check
        self.uncheck_img.hidden = true;    // Hide the red cross
        self.ok_button.enabled = true;     // Enable your validation button (or anything)

    } else {
        // Contrary of above
        self.uncheck_img.hidden = false;
        self.checkmark_img.hidden = true;
        self.ok_button.enabled= false;

    }
}
```

Feel free to be creative, like, instead of red cross and green check icons, you can add an error message, printed whenever the value is false, for example.

Comment: It might do the trick. Keep in mind that alert view pops out on your screen, but doesn't block anything. Before calling it, you have to NOT do all the saving stuff, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your goal but best way to check a mandatory field is to check for epty text on it

```
if (textField.text.length == 0)
{
   /* empty - show mandatory field alert */
}
else
{
   /* contains value */
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I knew how to test whether text box has no value. But I should show to the user like "Username is required or this field is required"

Comment: add an alertView in the empty if block

Comment: I need alternative for alertview. I need like what we will use in the web.

Comment: These are the best two TextField Validation API's
https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator
https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but I found the Sol in this article tip4

https://cocoacasts.com/five-simple-tips-to-make-user-friendly-forms-on-ios

here is a caption from the answer :

Form validation is another key component of a usable form. Not only do you need to validate the user's input before sending it to a backend, you need to tell the user if something's wrong with their input and how they can fix it.

Let's take the password text field as an example. I'd like to show an error message if the password is weak. Open ViewController.swift and declare an outlet, passwordValidationLabel, of type UILabel. This label shows the error message to the user if the password isn't strong.
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
// MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var passwordValidationLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Open Main.storyboard and insert a label below the password text field. Connect the label to the passwordValidationLabel outlet.

We're going to implement a simple validation method that is triggered when the user taps the return or done key. At the moment, we only validate the password text field. This is what the validate(_:) method looks like.
    // MARK: - Helper Methods

fileprivate func validate(_ textField: UITextField) -> (Bool, String?) {
    guard let text = textField.text else {
        return (false, nil)
    }

```
if textField == passwordTextField {
    return (text.characters.count >= 6, "Your password is too short.")
}

return (text.characters.count > 0, "This field cannot be empty.")
}
```

The validate(_:) method accepts a UITextField instance as its only argument and return a tuple of type (Bool, String?). As I mentioned, we're only validating the password text field at the moment. The tuple the method returns includes the result of the validation as well as an optional error message to show to the user.

We also need to update the textFieldShouldReturn(_:) method of the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. If the password text field is the first responder when the user taps the return key, we validate the text field's text. We only make the email text field the first responder if validation succeeds. We also update the password validation label with the error message and show or hide the password validation label.

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch textField {
    case firstNameTextField:
        lastNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    case lastNameTextField:
        passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    case passwordTextField:
        // Validate Text Field
        let (valid, message) = validate(textField)

        if valid {
            emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        // Update Password Validation Label
        self.passwordValidationLabel.text = message

        // Show/Hide Password Validation Label
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.passwordValidationLabel.isHidden = valid
        })
    default:
        emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}

}
```

In viewDidLoad(), we invoke a helper method, setupView(). In setupView(), we hide the validation label.
    // MARK: - View Life Cycle

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Setup View
setupView()
}

// MARK: - View Methods

fileprivate func setupView() {
// Configure Password Validation Label
passwordValidationLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Build and run the application to test the validation we implemented. You can set the text color of the validation label to red to catch the user's eye.
[image]
hope this can help you

Comment: Bent, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)